# Confusion with differential equation's periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions, bifurcation, delay-differential-equations

It is known that if $0<\epsilon<<1$ then differential equation with delay
$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon\right)x(t-1)[1+x(t)]=0$$
has periodic solution.

In one book author introduces the algorithm to find this solution following:

First of all, let's normalize time by $t=(1+c)\tau, -1<c<1$ which gives us
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}x(\tau)+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon\right)(1+c)x(\tau-1)[1+x(\tau)]=0.$$
The next step is to consider that
$$x(τ,ζ)=ζcos⁡\sigma_0\tau+ζ^2 x_2 (τ)+ζ^3 x_3 (τ)+⋯,$$
$$ε(ζ)=b_2 ζ^2+b_4 ζ^4+⋯,$$
$$c(ζ)=c_2 ζ^2+c_4 ζ^4+⋯,$$
assuming

$$\int_0^\frac{2\pi}{\sigma_0}x(τ,ζ)sin⁡\sigma_0\tau d\tau\equiv0,$$
$$\int_0^\frac{2\pi}{\sigma_0}x(τ,ζ)cos⁡\sigma_0\tau d\tau\equiv\frac{\pi}{\sigma_0}ζ,$$
$$x(τ,0)\equiv0,$$
$$\frac{d}{dζ}x(τ,ζ)|_{ζ=0}\equiv cos⁡\sigma_0\tau,$$
where $\sigma_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in this case.

We substitute $x(τ,ζ), ε(ζ), c(ζ)$ in our differential equation, then equate coefficients to the same ζ degrees. For the first two ($ζ^2$ and $ζ^3$) we would get

$$ζ^2: \frac{d}{d\tau}x_2(\tau)+\frac{\pi}{2}x_2(τ-1)+\frac{\pi}{4}sin⁡πτ=0,$$
$$ζ^3: \frac{d}{d\tau}x_3(τ)+\frac{\pi}{2}x_3(τ-1)+(b_2+\frac{\pi}{2}c_2)  sin⁡\frac{\pi}{2}τ+\frac{\pi}{2}x_2 (τ)  sin⁡\frac{\pi}{2}τ+\frac{\pi}{2}x_2(τ-1)cos⁡\frac{\pi}{2}τ=0,$$
but the author gets
$$ζ^2: \frac{d}{d\tau}x_2(\tau)+\frac{\pi}{2}x_2(τ-1)+\frac{\pi}{4}sin⁡πτ=0,$$
$$ζ^3: \frac{d}{d\tau}x_3(τ)+\frac{\pi}{2}x_3(τ-1)+(b_2+\frac{\pi}{2}c_2)  sin⁡\frac{\pi}{2}τ+\frac{\pi}{2}x_2 (τ)  sin⁡\frac{\pi}{2}τ+\frac{\pi}{2}x_2(τ-1)cos⁡\frac{\pi}{2}τ+\frac{\pi^2}{4}c_2cos\frac{\pi}{2}\tau=0.$$
As you can see in the $ζ^3$ case, there is other term $\frac{\pi^2}{4}c_2cos\frac{\pi}{2}\tau$ which I do not understand where it is coming from. In the algorithm's explanation author brings something about Fourier series and recursive functions, but I can not understand russian language very well so I'll show you pictures of that part. Hopefully someone gets it and could explain/show me how to get that extra term.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]